# AndEngine: Multiple TimerHandlers

Tags: android, andengine

I've built a separate class extending AnimatedSprite, called 'Enemy'. I've created a few instances of the Enemy in my scene. Each one is supposed to have its own TimerHandler, which controls animation. However, the timers all seem to be linked, and each sprite changes its TileIndex at the same time. Here's the code:

```
package com.tahakki.folkprequel;

import java.util.Random;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.timer.ITimerCallback;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ContactListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;

public class Enemy extends AnimatedSprite{

private Body physB;
private PhysicsWorld physW = MainActivity.mPhysicsWorld;
private static final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0, 0);
private TimerHandler timer;
private Random rand = new Random();

public Enemy(float pX, float pY, TiledTextureRegion pTiledTextureRegion) {
    super(pX, pY, pTiledTextureRegion);

    this.setCurrentTileIndex(rand.nextInt(3));
    this.setScale(0.6f);
    physB = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physW, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    physB.setFixedRotation(true);
    physW.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, physB));

    timer = new TimerHandler(2 + (2*rand.nextFloat()), true, new ITimerCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            int random = rand.nextInt(3);
            Enemy.this.setCurrentTileIndex(random);
        }
    });
    this.registerUpdateHandler(timer);
}

}
```

Does anyone know how to let each object have its own independent timer? Thanks!

Comment: We're going to need to see more code than that?  Is the timer static?

Comment: No, I just define it as `private TimerHandler timer;`. Making it static has no apparent effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using the same TextureRegion for each enemy. If you dont copy them then try

```
Enemy e = new Enemy(x,y,yourTextureregion.deepCopy());
```